# jQuery hovering a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I really can't get my head around this one.

I'm trying to select `<a href="contact"><div id="res">Reserveren</div></a>`.

This is my jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#res').hover(
    function () {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#fff" });
    },
    function () {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#000" });
    }

  });
```

However, nothing is working. It doesn't change anything at all... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Bart

Comment: You haven't closed the opening bracket after the first .hover, change `}` on the 2nd to laste line to `});` for a start

Comment: I tried this, it did not change anything.

Comment: Relevant reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with the usage of <a> ?

Answer (score 7):

jQuery doesn't, and *can't*, animate `color` without using [a suitable plug-in](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/), or the [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/).

You can, however, take advantage of CSS transitions using class-names:

```
$('#res').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('animating');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('animating');
    });
```

With the following CSS:

```
#res { /* default styles */
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

#res.animating, /* hovered-class/animating styles */
.animating {
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZnG8C/).

Comment: [Yes, it does](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZnG8C/). (And, incidentally, you had a syntax-error (unexpected `}`), once *that* was removed it worked.)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I saw your JS Fiddle demo and I truly appreciate the effort you're putting into this, but on this side it isn't working at all... I probably just don't know enough about html/css/jQuery. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then *show your code*, and we can maybe help you to make it work.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to start. This div is located in a sidebar which I included using php on every page. To test this out I only linked to jQuery and javascript file on the index page. I copied all your code and just saved it, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Cause of the changed my div is now stretching full width and it's ugly as hell. I already regret trying jQuery lol.

Comment: To be honest, everything I tried with jQuery on my site does not work. Does this have anything to do with including certain part of the site in main files?

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter. I suspect it's got more to do with a misunderstanding of jQuery than anything else. Are you including the library properly?

Comment: <script src="jquery.js"></script> is the way I'm including it.

Answer (score 4):

there are multiple things wrong with the snippet

- the hover function has no closing brace.
- *backgroundColor* is not a property. you would give `background-color`
- color animations are not supported in jquery, please check jquery ui for support on that
  http://jqueryui.com/animate/

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#res').hover(
          function () {
              $(this).animate({"font-size": "90px" });
          },
          function () {
              $(this).animate({"font-size" : "12px" });
          }
      );
  });
  ```

​

Answer (score 0):

remove the animate

```
$('#res').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css("background","#fff");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css("background","#000");
    }
);
```

Even better would be to change the class of the selector

```
$('#res').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("on");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("on");
    }
);
```

Comment: I would actually want the background to change slowly from one color to another. I thought this was possible with the animate function?

Comment: Ah yes, it is - David Thomas suggestion is using css3 transitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#res').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css('background-color' ,'#fff');
    },
    function () {
      $(this).css('background-color' ,'#000');
  })
});
```

or use this plugin:
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/